# Struct being populated with duplicate data over and over

Tags: recursion, coldfusion

Consider the following code:

```
<cfset result.enrollments = {} />
<cfset result.enrollments = getCorrectionList(SESSION.id,SESSION.term) />
<cfdump var="#result#" /><Cfabort/>


<cffunction name="getCorrectionList">
    <cfargument name="id" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="term" required="true" type="numeric" default="#getCurrentSemester().code#" />

        <cfset result = {} />
        <cfset result.status = 500 />
        <cfset result.message = 'Unknown Error' />

        <cfhttp url="THERE IS A REAL URL HERE" />
        <cfif cfhttp.statusCode EQ '200 OK'>
            <cfset courses = deserializeJson(cfhttp.fileContent,false) />

            <cfif courses.recordCount EQ 0>
                <cfset result.message = 'You are not currently enrolled in any courses for #ARGUMENTS.term#' />
                <cfdump var="#result#" />
                <cfreturn result />
            </cfif>
<!--- MORE STUFF --->
```

Now when this runs I get an single struct output with two keys `message` and `status`. This is from the dump inside of the `getCorrectionList` function.

I then get a second struct output with the keys `enrollments`, `message`, and `status`. Inside the `enrollments` key is another struct with `enrollments`, `message`, and `status`. Inside that `enrollments` key is another struct with the same keys and so on 50 times with the last struct being empty.

Seems like some recursive actions is going on but where/how?

I have no idea what is going on. As you can see from my code there are no loops. I know the URL resolves correctly and it returns a query and has a recordcount. I can see the data dump at the right spots. But how can the `#result#` in the function show a single struct but the `#result#` outside the function show a 50 deep struct repeating itself. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: (Edit) It is because you are using a structure variable named "result" both inside *and* outside the function. Since the variable inside the function is not localized, you are essentially capturing the result of the function - inside itself. Thus creating a circular reference. Hence the dump. The solution is to localize the function local variables. Interestingly it only occurs in CF.  I have seen lack of scoping do some strange things, but that is a new one ;-)

Comment: To clarify, the code is not actually populating the structure over and over. It just seems that way because CFDump cannot resolve the circular reference when presenting the values.

Comment: You need to `var` the variable named `result`  - but I would suggest using a different name for it..and `var` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno why neither Leigh or Scott actually made their comments answers, but they're both right.

You have this reference to `result` outside your function:

```
<cfset result.enrollments = getCorrectionList(SESSION.id,SESSION.term) />
```

And at the end of your function you do this:

```
<cfreturn result />
```

Which in effect means you're doing this:

```
<cfset result.enrollments = result />
```

Meaning `result.enrollments` is a reference back to its own parent `result`.

And `<cfdump>` is duly displaying the circular reference.

As they both said, you need to localise your variables inside a function, either by `var`ing them:

```
<cfset var result = {} />
```

Or explicitly putting them in the `local` scope:

```
<cfset local.result = {} />
```

That will make the function's `result` be a discrete variable, not simply another reference to the calling code' `result` variable.

You should *always* localise your function variables, unless you specifically mean to be referencing a calling-code variable, in which event it makes you code clearer if you explicitly scope it to make it obvious what you mean, eg:

```
<cfset variables.result = {} />
```

But this is *not* what you are meaning to do here. Localise your function's variables.

Comment: IMO, "good answers" should have a little more substance (and ideally examples) than my comments. I decided to take the night off, but hoped you might pop in and post a more solid answer to this one in the mean time... you did not disappoint ;-)

Comment: Heh, fair enough. I reckon your comment was actually thorough enough, but it went and made me write-up *even more* so as to actually be doing a value-add in the answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that inside a function CF10 localized the variables by default and it wasn't necessary to do so. I'm guessing it does, but because I already have a result outside the function it's using that reference and not creating a new one?

Comment: Actually, just tested my theory and I was way wrong. Wow. Been doing this for a while now and I was making a very incorrect assumption. Either way, strange I didn't even see that the result wasn't set locally. Thanks.

Comment: @Leeish - While the variables should definitely be var/local scoped to avoid the issue, interestingly this behavior only occurs in ACF.  Both Lucee and Railo return a structure with only two keys: status and message.